# apply shadow and corner radius to a view, not the entire cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4

I have a table view cell, inside which I have a view. In the view, I have 2 labels and an image. I want the view to have shadow and corner radius, not the entire tableview cell. Some suggestions please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the shadow, I would create another view behind the actual view, and give it a different x or y position based on where you want the shadow to be angled from the view.    Then add your main view as a subclass of that shadow view.  Configure the shadow view to look like a shadow by changing the alpha and background color values.  For the corner radius, it's changed by `view.layer.cornerRadius = x`

Make sure to change the corner radius of the shadow view to equal the main views corner radius too, so it looks realistic.

I believe I understood the question correctly, please comment if I did not answer right.

Comment: if I write this -> self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor, I get the cell's shadowcolor set. I want to set the shadow color of my view, not the cell.

Comment: I'm guessing you have subclassed UITableViewCell?  Make sure you are configuring the view, not self.  Find your view inside your subclass, and do view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

Answer (score 0):

Use this UIView extension in your code. Select your view and in storyboard you can set properties values

```
    @IBDesignable extension UIView {

    /* The color of the shadow. Defaults to opaque black. Colors created
     * from patterns are currently NOT supported. Animatable. */
    @IBInspectable var shadowColor: UIColor? {
        set {
            layer.shadowColor = newValue!.cgColor
        }
        get {
            if let color = layer.shadowColor {
                return UIColor(cgColor:color)
            }
            else {
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var clipBounds: Bool {
        set {
            clipsToBounds = newValue
        }
        get {
            return clipsToBounds
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        } get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat {
        set {
            layer.borderWidth = newValue
        } get {
            return layer.borderWidth
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
        set {
            layer.borderColor = newValue?.cgColor
        }
        get {
            if let color = layer.borderColor {
                return UIColor(cgColor:color)
            }
            else {
                return nil
            }
        }

    }
    @IBInspectable var borderColorCode: CGColor? {
        set {
            layer.borderColor = newValue
        } get {
            return layer.borderColor
        }
    }
    /* The opacity of the shadow. Defaults to 0. Specifying a value outside the
     * [0,1] range will give undefined results. Animatable. */
    @IBInspectable var shadowOpacity: Float {
        set {
            layer.shadowOpacity = newValue
        }
        get {
            return layer.shadowOpacity
        }
    }

    /* The shadow offset. Defaults to (0, -3). Animatable. */
    @IBInspectable var shadowOffset: CGPoint {
        set {
            layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: newValue.x, height: newValue.y)
        }
        get {
            return CGPoint(x: layer.shadowOffset.width, y:layer.shadowOffset.height)
        }
    }

    /* The blur radius used to create the shadow. Defaults to 3. Animatable. */
    @IBInspectable var shadowRadius: CGFloat {
        set {
            layer.shadowRadius = newValue
        }
        get {
            return layer.shadowRadius
        }
    }
}
```